# Check if interface{} is ptr to struct

Tags: go, pointers, struct, reflection, assertion

I would like to check if a given `f interface{}` function argument is a pointer to a struct, but am struggling somehow:

Updated snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    // Switch f between being a pointer or not
    f := &struct{Foo string}{"Bar"}

    if err := something(f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

}

func something(f interface{}) error {

    if reflect.ValueOf(f).Kind() != reflect.Struct  {
        return fmt.Errorf("not struct; is %s", reflect.ValueOf(f).Kind().String())
    }

    if reflect.ValueOf(f).Kind() != reflect.Ptr  {
        return fmt.Errorf("not ptr; is %s", reflect.ValueOf(f).Kind().String())
    }

    // Deal with element values...
    t := reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Type().String(), t.Field(i).Interface())
    }

    return nil
}
```

If `f` is passed to function as pointer i get a `not struct; is ptr`.

If `f` is passed to function as struct i get a `not ptr; is struct`.

Is there any way to make sure that the interface is a pointer to a struct? Seems like as soon as `f` is a pointer any further checks via reflection are not usable here. Many other solutions I found could get handled via type assertions but I just do not know what is coming in here. Basically it could be literally anything.

Sure I could just use the pointer check and leave everything else as a "developer error". I just thought I could handle it somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: How could it possibly be a pointer and a struct at the same time? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am using `reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()` to later on read field values etc. This fails if not `&struct` with `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value`. I am just trying to catch that.

Comment: So you are looking for a pointer _to_ a struct?

Comment: I updated the example code. If those two checks are getting removed and function is triggered with just just a struct it panics. Just wanted to catch that. Sure it can not be a struct AND a ptr at the same time. Just thought refelction could help me out.

Comment: I just clarified question

Comment: It makes no sense to check that the kind is both of 2 mutually exclusive options. If you want a pointer to a struct, check for that. If you want either, then just deference the pointer.

Comment: Perfect. Dereferencing! That was it... First check for pointer, dereference, and than check for struct. Thanks for pointing me the correct way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code. Check for the pointer, dereference the pointer and check for a struct.

```
func something(f interface{}) error {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr  {
        return fmt.Errorf("not ptr; is %T", f)
    }
    v := v.Elem() // dereference the pointer
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct  {
        return fmt.Errorf("not struct; is %T", f)
    }
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := t.Field(i)
        fmt.Println(sf.Name, v.Field(i).Interface())
    }
    return nil
}
```